# Creating a git branch with a specific upstream branch that tracks an origin branch

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-branch

I have a remote repository on github `upstream` that is cloned of another github repository `origin`. The `origin` repository has several branches: `master`, `v1_x`, `v2_x`. I'd like to fix a bug in `v1_x`, and then forward port that change to the other branches `v2_x` and `master`.

How do I set up/create a branch in my local repository to track `origin/v1_x`, and push to a feature branch `upstream/my_awesome_bug_fix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up your branch to track `origin/v1_x`:

```
git checkout -b my_awesome_bug_fix -t origin/v1_x
```

Then you can get updates from `origin` with:

```
git pull
```

To push your branch to `upstream`:

```
git push upstream my_awesome_bug_fix
```

I would probably keep it this way for clarity and explicitness of what's being sent where. But, if you want to be able to use both `git pull` and `git push` on your branch without specifying the remote, be sure you have `push.default` set to "current", and add a [push url](http://sleepycoders.blogspot.com/2012/05/different-git-push-pullfetch-urls.html) to your origin remote:

```
git config push.default current
git remote set-url --push origin <upstream-url>
```

Now `git pull` should fetch and merge changes from `v1_x` on `origin`, and `git push` should push changes to `my_awesome_bug_fix` on `upstream`.